# DI - how to "do work" and not in constructor

Tags: constructor, dependency-injection, spring.net

Theoretical question: The best practice is not to do any work in constructor, not new, nothing besides setting members.

In the simple example (dependency injection) with the need to load a file from disk to a member in order for the class to work properly, where should I do the "work"? In some initialize function I need to remember to invoke?

For example:

```
XDocument.Load(someFilePath) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to not do any work in *injection constructors* as Mark Seemann clearly explains [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). So in case you need to load a file from disk, you should either do it during startup (if possible), or postpone the creation and do it after the object graph is built. This is usually not a nasty workaround, and Lazy is a great mechanism to postpone the creation of things. Example:

```
class ApplicationConfiguration
{
    private readonly Lazy<XDocument> configFile;

    public ApplicationConfiguration(Lazy<XDocument> configFile) {
        this.configFile = configFile;
    }

    public T GetValue<T>(string key) {
        return (T)this.configFile.Value.Root.Find(key).Value;
    }
}
```

But one warning about `Lazy<T>`. Although it can (and should) be used to postpone the creation of things, make sure that you don't abuse it as a leaky abstraction. For instance, don't inject the same `Lazy<T>` dependency in many classes. For instance, say that you have an `ILogger` abstraction and you get an implementation that is time expensive to create. You might be tempted to start injecting `Lazy<ILogger>` all over the place, but now you're leaking implementation details, since the fact that this logger is expensive to create is an implementation details, but now all consumers of `ILogger` know about this, and you just have to accidentally inject `ILogger` directly once to break this optimization.

So instead, create a proxy class that implements `ILogger` and depends on `Lazy<ILogger>` and inject this proxy into all consumers. This way all consumers can keep depending on `ILogger`, without the need to know that the creation of the logger is delayed.